# How to fix "Application has too many object types" error on Open Graph Dashboard?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a web application integrated into facebook's open graph, and had initially created many objects (20 or 30), representing each item type on the application, I quickly found that to the the wrong way to go about it, and it would be better to create object types, and I managed to simplify the app to 6 objects. But after deleting almost all objects, I can't add a 7th object, as I still get the "Application has too many object types." error. How to I get rid of it?